On the variant of Farkas Lemma
We know the Farkas Lemma is:
let $c, a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m,$ $c$ is not a zero vector. Then precisely one of the following statements is true.
$$\text{(1) }  c^\top x < 0, \: a^\top_i x \geq 0 \text{ has a solution }$$
$$\text{(2) } \text{there exist } \mu_1 \geq 0, \ldots, \mu_m \geq 0, \text{ such that } c = \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i a_i $$
Now I want to modify this to the following statement
$$\text{(1) }  c^\top x \leq 0, \: a^\top_i x > 0 \text{ has a solution }$$
$$\text{(2) } \text{there exist } \mu_1 \geq 0, \ldots, \mu_m \geq 0, \text{ such that } c = \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i a_i $$
Is this variant of Farkas Lemma correct?
